# strategy to free memory from std container in case of bad_alloc exception

Tags: c++, memory-management, exception

i'm thinking in implementing the following strategy:

When handling a `std::bad_alloc` exception in a class method, memory will be attempted to be free whenever possible/meaningful before rethrowing the exception. So if an object has some std containers (std::vector<>) that can be freed, then we might do something like:

```
catch( std::bad_alloc& e ) {
  //free any memory in my std::vector member, how? by doing this dirty hack
  ~myVec();
  new ( &myVec) std::vector<myType>();
  throw; //rethrow exception
}
```

**Question:** is the above "dirty hack" a safe strategy to deallocate memory on the way while a exception is being unrolled? what are the pros and cons?

Comment: When an exception is thrown, the stack will unwind, and any object on it will have it's destructor called. I don't understand your question, because RAII is supposed to handle those cases.

Comment: @EtiennedeMartel, sure, that covers objects in the stack. Here i'm talking about members in the object handling the exception. The semantics of an error obviously have to be that such an error means the member data is not required anymore

Comment: @lurscher: Why? If the class needs to be cleaned up, it will be on the stack or owned by a smart pointer. Else, it does not need to be cleaned up. Throwing an exception in a class method does not at all mean that the member variables need to be cleared.

Comment: @lurscher If a method other than a constructor throws an exception, then the object still exists: no need to destroy all its member (unless your class design is messy, which might indicate a larger problem).

Comment: @DeadMg, i didn't imply that it is required in general, i'm just wondering if its a safe strategy to help the system recover from such an error, also, assuming that it makes semantic sense to free this member

Comment: @EtiennedeMartel i'm very aware of what you say. I'm not destroying the current object, just forcing memory reset of some members that will not be needed for now

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no need for you to do any such- the vector will be destructed automatically. That's how RAII works. Even if you wish to clear the vector in some other situation, it comes with a `clear()` method. Or you can just do `vec = std::vector<T>();`.

Comment: first, clear does not deallocate memory, it just resets the size (the buffer is still held). second, the vector here is a member of an object that becomes useless because of the error, but it does not live in the stack (the this object has not been deallocated yet, or maybe it won't be at all)

Comment: @lurscher Why does it become useless?

Comment: @lurscher: And if it has become useless, then it should be in the stack/owned by smart pointer. Also, `vector` comes with a `shrink_to_fit()` method.

Comment: @lurscher If the object becomes useless because of the memory error then you should catch the bad_alloc exception at a location that can destroy the useless object. I don't see any particular call for the object itself to handle this. Also, if you know you have some memory that you can free when a bad_alloc occurs then you could register a new_handler that can free that memory and possibly allow the allocation to succeed so the object doesn't become useless in the first place.

Comment: @DeadMG, i'm afraid the shrink_to_fit might attempt a reallocation to copy in a smaller buffer. In any case i'll accept your answer